# Fs: Getting folder name from reddirSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to log all files with the file extension `.js` from each folder

```
const fs = require('fs')

const folders = fs 
    .readdirSync('./commands/')

for (const folder in folders) {
    const files = fs   
        .readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}/`)
        .filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

    for (const file in files) {
        console.log(file)
    }
}
```

I Get The Error

> **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands/0/'**

Which I Assume `0` Is The Folder's Index, However I Want The Folder's Name Instead

How Can I Return The Folder name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for in` is a loop over the property names of an object. You want `for of`, a loop over the values of an iterable.

```js
for (const folder of folders) {
```

```js
    for (const file of files) {
```